# Access extension's functions from webpage in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to write an extension to Firefox that would allow me to access internal functions/classes/objects of it from my webpage. I want them to be visible and accesible in DOM. It worked when extension was loaded as a component from chrome.manifest file but it doesn't seem that it's possible in e10s (multiprocess Firefox) anymore. 
So I was trying and trying and the best option I have found so far seems to be using exportFunction, createObjectIn and cloneInto functions. They work fine when expected to make objects visible from pages loaded by the extension itself but not from remote ones.
I'm using Addon-SDK now and my code is

And then

```
function injectTest(event) {
    let domWindow = event.subject;

//This creates and object that is always visible but never accesible from page not loaded by the extension     
foo = Cu.createObjectIn(domWindow.wrappedJSObject, {defineAs: "testSDK"});     
//This exports my function fine but I can export it only into an existing object
//That's why I'm using "crypto" here
Cu.exportFunction(test.bind(this, domWindow),
                    domWindow.crypto.wrappedJSObject,
                    { defineAs: "test" });


//This exports my function to my object but only on pages loaded by the extension    
Cu.exportFunction(test.bind(this, domWindow),
                    foo,
                    { defineAs: "test2" });

//Same here, cloned_var seems to be not accesible from remote webpage
var to_be_cloned = {"greet" : "hey"};
    foo.cloned_var = Cu.cloneInto(to_be_cloned, foo);
}



  exports.main = function(options, callbacks) {
      if (!gInitialized &&
          (options.loadReason == "startup" ||
           options.loadReason == "install" ||
           options.loadReason == "enable")) {
        log("initializing - " +  options.loadReason);
        try {
          events.on("content-document-global-created", injectTest);
        } catch (error) {
          log(error);
        }
        gInitialized = true;
      }
    };
```

I'm totally new to javascript and Firefox extensions so I have no idea how to make it work. What I'm doing wrong? Is there any better idea to access extension's objects?

Thank you in advance for help.

@edit 19.05.15
Tried using page-mod. It does work but not as well as I need.
main.js file

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data; 
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod"); 

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "mywebsite",
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("cscript.js")],
    contentScript: 'window.alert("Page matches ruleset");'
});
```

cscript.js file (in data folder)

```
var contentScriptObject = {
    "greeting" : "hello from add-on",
    b: 1,

    powitaj: function(){
    return(this.greeting);
    }, //when called from console returns "hello from add-on"


    is_b: function(){
        if(b){
        return true;
        }else{
        return false;
        }
    }, //undefined

    is_thisb: function(){
        if(this.b){
        return true;
        }else{
        return false;
        }
    }, //returns 1

    func: function(){
    console.log("ok")
    }, //returns "ok"

    is_func: function(){
        func();         
    }, //undefined

    is_thisfunc:function(){
        this.func();
    } //undefined

};
```

So from my website I can access inner variables (actually variables defined globally too and modify them as well), I can access inner functions (not outer - not included in the code) but my inner functions cannot call each other and I'd like to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To run chrome-privileged code in a e10s-content process you'll need [framescripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox)

The SDK has some wrapper modules to simplify the communication and module loading between [parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/remote_parent) and [child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/remote_child) process

If you only need `exportFunction`/`cloneInto`/`createObjectIn` then using the [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) module may be sufficient, if i recall correctly those helpers are made available in its context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried framescripts but was only able to use exportFunctions to an instance (created with createObjectIn and)of my top level object but they couldn't call each other then unfortunately. 
I will look into parent/child and that page-mod though.